# How to dock tools panel in Adobe Premiere Pro 22.3.1 after un-docking it?

Tags: adobe-premiere

I am using Adobe Premiere Pro 22.3.1.

I have un-docked tools panel and it seems there is no way to dock it back in any panels group.

There is no any title or hands on the top.

I can drag it over the window - but dropping it - it remains undocked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm using 23.2.0 and also was unable to re-dock the Tools panel. All other panels work normally. I was having the same problem as the OP until I read the comment clarifying the click area is much smaller than shown by the red dot in the top answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Dock the Tools panel to the Options panel

Click and drag the Tools panel to re-dock it.

Note that you must click below window bar and just before the menu items.

See orange dot <sup>[image]</sup> in image below for click location.  Please note that I have added the orange dot myself to the picture to show the click placement.  It does not exist in the actual GUI.

The actual click area is about 2 pixels in height (much smaller than the orange dot in the graphic.)

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: it works, thanks a lot. Btw the orange dot is not visible and the area for pointers click is about a pair of pixels in size. Very strange

Comment: I put the orange dot so that you could tell where to click.  It isn't part of the GUI.  I have updated my answer so as not to confuse anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

#### It seems there is no way to dock it back in any panels group

> **Dock the Tools panel to the Options panel**
>
> 1. In the Tools panel, click the panel menu icon.
> 2. Select Dock In Options Panel.

Source: [Working with Panels in Premiere Pro](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/premiere-pro/using/panels.html)

Or:

> Click the 3-bar menu of the floating panel, and drag it to the panel
> you want to dock it in. You get the various blue blocks from the
> sides, top/bottom or middle, which tell you where it's going to go if
> you let up.
>
> If a side/top/bottom is blue, it will go to that side as a separate
> panel. If the middle is blue, it will be in that panel as a separate
> tab.

Source: [Solved: docking a floating panel - Adobe Support Community - 5165424](https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro-discussions/docking-a-floating-panel/td-p/5165424)

Comment: My answer originally started out like yours based on the same search results, but I determined it was not in fact the case. I played around in Premiere Pro for a few minutes and finally figured out how it is done and that is what my answer was ultimately based on.